# Show a datagridview when a specific user is connect

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I want to show specific data when a specific user is connect. If it's an administrator, i want to retrieve all the data, NULL value include from DB. When an operator is connect, i want to retrieve all the data except the ones for "ReportingOperator = NULL".

Here is my code, page showing datagridview :

```
public partial class Repair : Form
{


    public Repair()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Main ss = new Main();

        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");

        if(ss.label3.Text == "admin")
        {
            maConnexion.Open();
            SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly.";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            maConnexion.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            maConnexion.Open();
            SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE ReportingOperator != NULL";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            maConnexion.Close();
        }








    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /** SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");

         maConnexion.Open();

         string Var1 = textBox1.Text;
         SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1);
         command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE BoardName=@BoardName OR Machine=@Machine OR SerialNum=@SerialNum OR FComponent=@FComponent AND ReportingOperator != NULL";
         SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         sda.Fill(ds);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];**/




    }



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        this.Hide();
        Main ff = new Main();
        ff.Show();




    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");

        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {

                maConnexion.Open();

                string Var1 = textBox1.Text;
                SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1 + "%");
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE BoardName LIKE @BoardName OR Machine LIKE @Machine OR SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum OR FComponent LIKE @FComponent";
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                maConnexion.Close();


            }




        }
    }
```

Page where i have information about login :

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Login login;

    public Main()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        button2.Enabled = ViewModel.Instance.IsAdmin;

        if(button2.Enabled == true)
        {
            label3.Text = "admin";
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Text = "operator";
        }

    }

    public Main(Login login)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label3.Text = login.textBox1.Text;

        this.login = login;

        if (login.textBox1.Text == "admin" && login.textBox2.Text == "root")
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;

        }
        else
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Repair form3 = new Repair();
        this.Hide();

        form3.Show();

    }



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Admin form4 = new Admin();
        this.Hide();
        form4.Show();
    }



    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Login().Show();
        this.Hide();
        //MessageBox.Show("Vous êtes déconnecté");


    }





}
```

I've tried a "if" condition, but it seems to not work, or at least if i connect in operator it doesn't enter in the "else" condition.

Thank you !

Comment: The debugger will be better-suited to help you than us..

Comment: But i'm not sure of what i wrote in my condition and if the "Main main = new Main()" is the previous form that contains the informations of the label and not a new instance with all blanks informations. And debugger can't help me for this.

Comment: _But i'm not sure of what i wrote in my condition_ Huh? And how would we know??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Can I suggest you a simpler method ? .As it seems to be a Winform Application
Add a static variable in program.cs and as UserType

```
Public Static String UserType="";
```

Then in the page where you are Doing the

```
    if (login.textBox1.Text == "admin" && login.textBox2.Text == "root")
            {
                button2.Enabled = true;
    Program.UserType="admin";
            }
            else
            {
                button2.Enabled = false;
 Program.UserType="User";

            }
```

And in your DataRetreiwal form

```
 public Repair()
    {
        InitializeComponent();       

        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();
        SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
        if (Program.UserType == "admin")
        {

            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly.";

        }
        else
        {

            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE ReportingOperator != NULL";


        }
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        maConnexion.Close();

    }
```

Comment: So you mean that variable in program.cs are global and accessible from every forms ?